# SSL with NGINX with .pem files

Tags: nginx, ssl

I need to add SSL certificate for my domain for my website on my NGINX server.

My domain provider gave me a zip file to download, which contains:

```
domain.cert.pem
intermediate.cert.pem
private.key.pem
public.key.pem
```

[For clarity: I did not rename 'domain', it is called `domain.cert.pem`]

I'm confused as to what to do, because all the tutorials I can find online require different files, some ending with .crt.

Does anyone have any advice?

---

My nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  ssl on;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  ssl_certificate /usr/src/app/domain.cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/src/app/private.key.pem;

  # vue app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /usr/src/app/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

Error when restarting nginx:

```
nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509("/usr/src/app/domain.ce
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat intermediate.cert.pem >> domain.cert.pem`

In your nginx conf:

```
server {
    ...
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/domain.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private.key.pem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alaister, I followed your instructions but now I get an error when I restart nginx, I have copied the error and my conf file to my main post

Comment: @Joseph Could you please show the full error message? Thanks.

Comment: solved it! I found this post, my concatenated domain.cert.pem file didn't have a new line between the two keys. I added a line break and it works. Thank you very much for your help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514704/ssl-on-nginx-throws-error-ssl-error0908f066pem-routinesget-header-and-data